# How to intersect boolean subarrays for True values?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, boolean

I know that Numpy provides [`logical_and()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) which allows us to intersect two boolean arrays for True values only (True and True would yield True while True and False would yield False). For example,

```
a = np.array([True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
b = np.array([False,  True,  True,  True,  False], dtype=bool)

np.logical_and(a, b)
> array([False, False, False, True, False], dtype=bool)
```

However, I'm wondering how I can apply this to two subarrays in an overall array? For example, consider the array:

```
[[[ True,  True], [ True, False]], [[ True, False], [False,  True]]]
```

The two subarrays I'm looking to intersect are:

```
[[ True,  True], [ True, False]]
```

and

```
[[ True, False], [False,  True]]
```

which should yield:

```
[[ True, False], [False,  False]]
```

Is there a way to specify that I want to apply logical_and() to the outermost subarrays to combine the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) along the first axis:

```
>>> a = np.array([[[ True,  True], [ True, False]], [[ True, False], [False,  True]]])
>>> np.logical_and.reduce(a, axis=0)

array([[ True, False],
       [False, False]])
```

This works even when you have more than two "sub-arrays" in your outer array. I prefer this over the unpacking approach because it allows you to apply your function (`np.logical_and`) over *any* axis of your array.

Comment: Just a reminder, `np.all` and `np.logical_and.reduce` is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to do:

```py
import numpy as np

output = np.logical_and(a[:, 0], a[:, 1])
```

This simply slices your arrays so that you can use logical_and the way your results suggest.